# How does a motherboard become an open circuit after shutdown of PC/laptop?

Tags: motherboard, computer-building, computer-architecture

When I press power switch in my laptop the pins get connected and therefore it makes a close circuit for power supply.

But when I shutdown my laptop how the pins get disconnected?

How the does laptop stop supplying power?

Comment: @John I don't think that's what he asking.

Comment: @john I think he is asking about momentary switches, I dont think he is communicating that correctly.

Comment: The easiest way to explain this: The power button is not a switch. It is effectively a logical relay that tells the computer to start. And if that same power button is pressed when the computer is on, the computer knows how to power off the computer. It is all logic and not a literal switch like a light switch.

Comment: @Giacomo1968, a [relay is an electrically operated switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relay). One where a current between some pins creates a magnetic field in a coil that then operates the switch contacts (or something like that). The pushbutton isn't a relay, it's a switch, even though just a momentary contact switch. The (always-on circuitry on the) motherboard then interprets the signal and might decide to power on/off the machine. Yes, it's all logic, but the power switch is still a switch, just one that switches a control signal and not the main power itself.

Comment: @ilkkachu Yes. You are right. That is why I used the word-combo, “logical relay” and then said, “It is all logic and not a literal switch like a light switch.”

Answer (score 6):

Modern computers are not like typical electrical appliances.  They never truly turn 100% off.  There are reason for this, but that is outside the scope of the question, but this is done to accommodate low power states, like [suspend](https://computerbusiness.com/solved/what-are-the-different-power-states-of-advanced-power-management/).

Power switches on computers are of the "[momentary](https://www.tech-faq.com/momentary-switch.html)" kind (typically [normally open](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/images/Normally_Open_Push_Button_Diagrams.png)).  The computer is always drawing a very small amount of power to see if the power button or keyboard is pressed, or if the mouse is moved (depending on state).  When this power button is pressed, the circuit that monitors for these is complete and the computer will "wake up" from its current low power state (like sleep).  Alternatively, pressing the power button while the computer is fully on, will notify the computer, which tells the operating system to go into a low power state, such as sleep, suspend, hibernate, or off.

Very old computers used regular on/off switches, which complete cut power.  However, those are no longer in use.  There are some more modern devices that might use a sliding switch to prevent accidentally turning a device on or off, but they still use the same [Advanced Power Management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Power_Management) the momentary switches use.

Comment: Most ATX power supplies I've seen also have a hard on/off switch, it'd be at the rear side of the whole computer, next to the power cable. Flipping that would make the computer turn "100 % off".

Answer (score 6):

#### The Power Switch is not an off/switch.

When you press it a circuit is completed and send a signal. It has a spring under it so when it is released the circuit is open again.

So a very short signal is sent.

> How does a power button work technically?
>
> The power button has a cable, which is connected to two pins on the motherboard. By pressing the power button, a circuit is closed on the mainboard. At that moment, the power supply receives the signal to supply the computer with power and thus start up.

Source: [Nice to know: What is a power button?](https://www.spo-comm.de/en/blog/know-how/nice-to-know-what-is-a-power-button)

#### So what happens when you press the power button on a laptop that is on?

Pressing it sends a signal to the running operating system.

> When you press the power button on your computer’s case, it doesn’t suddenly cut power — it sends a signal to the operating system and tells it to shut down. The operating system can also understand multiple types of ACPI signals, which is how some laptops are able to have separate power and sleep buttons.
>
> And, when you click Shut Down in Windows, it uses ACPI to send a signal to your computer’s hardware, telling it to cut the power so you don’t have to press the power button by hand.

#### The Power Button is Smart

> In other words, your computer’s power button is smart enough to do the right thing. You can just press the power button on your case to shut it down. Bear in mind that this power button can be configured to do different things, so you can have your computer shut down, sleep, or hibernate when you press the power button.

#### Holding Down the Power Button Still Cuts Power to the Computer

> Your computer’s power button is smart, but this might be a problem in some situations. For example, if Windows is frozen and you press the power button, the computer would send the appropriate ACPI signal to Windows, but Windows wouldn’t be able to respond. Your computer would stay frozen and not shut down.
>
> For this reason, there’s a way to forcibly cut power to your computer in case you ever run into a problem. Just press the power button and hold it down. After a few seconds, the power will be cut to your computer and it will suddenly shut down. This is normally a bad idea, as it can lead to lost data, file system corruption, and other issues. However, if your computer is frozen and the power button isn’t working, it’s a failsafe you have available. This allows you to power cycle laptops when you can’t remove the battery.

Source: [Yes, It’s Okay to Shut Down Your Computer With the Power Button](https://www.howtogeek.com/181295/yes-its-okay-to-shut-down-your-computer-with-the-power-button/)

Further Reading:

- [ACPI Power Management](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/publications/library/proceedings/usenix02/tech/freenix/full_papers/watanabe/watanabe_html/node6.html)
- [Device power management - Windows drivers | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/bringup/device-power-management)
- [Advanced Configuration and Power Interface - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface)